# How to create a new save and load it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

What I'm trying to do:

[image: Main menu]

When I press the play button appears the panel with +. I made a simple script for the + button

```
    public void addSave()
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        File.Delete("Assets/Game1.unity");//If there is already a save then delete it
        i = 0;
    }
    if (i == 0)
    {
        File.Copy("Assets/Game.unity", "Assets/Game1.unity");//And copy the scene to make the new one.
        OpenSave.SetActive(true);
        i++;
    }
}
```

When I press on  [image: Save image] it has to load the Game1.unity but it says: "Scene 'Game1' couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded." So how do I add it to the build settings in the script?

I've found [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/saving-and-loading-player-game-data-in-unity/) but how do I make a new scene before the gameplay?

Edit: I've added the Game1.unity to build settings manually so the + button just resets the game. But maybe there is a better way to do this?

Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using scenes to save and load your game. Actually it is better to use just a master scene for everything (Unity scene system is ugly and slow).

You can use any serialization method depending on your needs such as xml, json,protocol buffers or the ones in the Asset Store. Serialization is much more flexible and manageable for these kind of things.

Comment: So I have to store stats in the file and then load them?

Comment: Yes read the data from the serialized file and build your map or load your stats according to that. You can make a main menu parent object and disable that after loading your map this way you don't have to load a new scene. Pretty much anything can be stored this way.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll do that

Comment: What do I do if I have a lot of items that i can interact with (for instance just change a texture) how do I save all of them? Shoud I make booleans for them and store it like that?

Comment: I would probably make an enum for the  type of the ingame object and use component model programming to add that behaviour depending on enum. For example if you have an enemy object add enemy behaviour component to that object while instantiating. Search for component based programming to learn more.